# Page transition using Ionic Animation in Ionic 5

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I created a custom page transition animation using [Ionic Animation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/animations). So, when clicked on About button in home page, it should take you to the about page with no animation. But when clicked on the back button icon in About page, the animation seem to work.

Here's a gist of my `nav-animation` file.

```
  if (opts.direction === 'forward') {
    return animationCtrl
      .create()
      .addElement(opts.enteringEl)
      .duration(DURATION)
      .fromTo('transform', 'translateX(400px)', 'translateX(0px)');
  } else {
    const rootAnimation = animationCtrl
      .create()
      .addElement(opts.enteringEl)
      .duration(DURATION)
      .fromTo('transform', 'translateX(-400px)', 'translateX(0px)');
    const leavingAnimation = animationCtrl
      .create()
      .addElement(opts.leavingEl)
      .duration(DURATION)
      .fromTo('transform', 'translateX(-400px)', 'translateX(0px)');
    return animationCtrl
      .create()
      .addAnimation([rootAnimation, leavingAnimation]);
  }
```

I created a working example using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-page-transition-animation?file=src%2Fapp%2Fanimations%2Fnav-animation.ts). Could anyone please help?